# Basic jQuery plugin for flash-based single file upload?

Tags: javascript, jquery, flash, upload, file-upload

I'm looking for a simple jquery plugin to upload a file via flash.

What I want:

- ability for the script to interpret an XML response from the server

What I don't want:

- multiple file upload
- progress indicator and all the bells & whistles

Answer (score 0):

http://www.uploadify.com/ - View their [single-file-upload demo](http://www.uploadify.com/demo/).

Their [documentation](http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/) contains information about return-data, and how you can work with it.